# How to prevent ::before / ::after elements influencing the breaking behaviour of spans?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Since there are no spaces in between the `<span>` elements, I expect them not to wrap but all sit on the same line, which seems to be the case in all browsers

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span>Fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span><span>foo</span><span>Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar</span><span>bar</span>
```

But when adding a `::before` tooltip element this behaviour changes. While they stay on the same line in Firefox (114), they start wrapping in Safari (16) and Chrome (114).

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}

span::before {
  content: 'tooltip';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 100ms;
}

span:hover::before {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<span>Fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span><span>foo</span><span>Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar</span><span>bar</span>
```

Why is that and is there a way to prevent it?

Different `display` options on the `::before` elements didn't have an effect.

But I just noticed that setting `inline-block` on the `span`s actually seems to have the same effect as adding the `::before` element

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>Fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span><span>foo</span><span>Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar</span><span>bar</span>
```

Is there a logical explanation for the wrapping, or can this be considered unexpected behaviour?

**Since in the real example there are whitespaces which should break, wrapping everything in a `white-space: nowrap;` container isn't an option.**

Here's an example with whitespaces where `FoooooooBaaaaaaar` should stay together and not split into two lines

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}

span::after {
  content: 'tooltip';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 100ms;
}

span:hover::after {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span>
```

While the abstract examples already illustrate the problem, here's also a more realistic one: Given a sentence that contains special characters such as quotation marks and parentheses, and words that are a combination of two words. For styling purposes, and because the words have a translation tooltip, everything is split into span elements.

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}

.word::after {
  content: 'tooltip';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 100ms;
}

.word:hover::after {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
This is an "example sentence" containing a comboword and also something in (parenthesis).<br><br>

<span class="word">This</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">is</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">an</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="char">"</span><span class="word">example</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">sentence</span><span class="char">"</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">containing</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">a</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">combo</span><span class="word">word</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">and</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">also</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">something</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">in</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="char">(</span><span class="word">parenthesis</span><span class="char">)</span><span class="char">.</span>
```

Usually there wouldn't be a break between the special characters and the word next to it or in betweeen the *comboword*, but with the `::after` element that's the case.

[image: unexpected breaks]

Comment: You should give the real example then

Comment: @dippas I added an example with spaces

Comment: Are you asking why firefox and chrome behave differently?

Comment: @SalmanA In firefox everything behaves as expected, so yes - part of the question is why that's not the case in Chrome and Safari plus if both *should* behave the same and if there's a way to solve the problem with the current behaviour nevertheless

Comment: This is a long standing bug (*[Issue 1024331: An out-of-flow element in phrasing content introduces a soft-wrap opportunity and breaks browser search](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1024331)*) in the chromium project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was reading [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-break-details) here and it says that:

> Out-of-flow elements and inline element boundaries do not introduce a
> forced line break or soft wrap opportunity in the flow.

Apparently, `position: absolute` elements as well as `</span><span>` should not generate a soft wrap; Chromimum based browsers are doing it wrong!

The article further states that:

> For Web-compatibility there is a soft wrap opportunity before and
> after each replaced element or other atomic inline, even when adjacent
> to a character that would normally suppress them, such as U+00A0
> NO-BREAK SPACE.

So `display: inline-block` elements could generate a soft wrap.

```css
body {
  font: medium monospace;
}
.test > span:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #FC0;
}
.test > span:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #CF0;
}
.test-1 > span {
  position: relative;
}
.test-1 > span::before {
  content: "tooltip";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .65);
}
.test-2 > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>position: absolute<br>should not wrap</h1>
<p class="test test-1"><span>Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span><span>Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span><span>Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span><span>Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span></p>

<h1>display: inline-block<br>should wrap</h1>
<p class="test test-2"><span>Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span><span>Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</span><span>Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span><span>Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! So if the behavior is not following the specs - is there a place to report it?

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/Home/, search for "report a bug"

Comment: I would've never thought of this, great find!

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are set to `position:absolute` are treated as block elements.

The description is here [mdn/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#description) and further linked there [mdn/block formatting context (BFC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

The problem is not the pseudo-element. The chrome inspector confirms `display:block` for `position:absolute` at `:before` under "Computed", whereas Firefox does not seem to assign a "display" attribute.

Unfortunately I don't have a 100% CSS solution. One approach would be to work with `display:none/block` so that the line breaks are the same in all browsers. With `display:block` and  and to transfering some sytles to hover you unfortunately lose the opacity transition effect and the line behaves strange if there is a tooltip at the beginning of the line.

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}

span::after {
  display: none;
}

span:hover::after {
  display: block;
  content: 'tooltip';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 100ms;
}
```

```html
<span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span>
```

You probably won't get around a javascript solution, where you then determine positions and set a (more global) tooltip relative to the spans parent element.

Comment: *...are treated as block elements.* Do you refer to the part *The (absolutely positioned) element establishes a new block formatting context (BFC) for its contents.*? That's about the inner behavior? Concerning the outer it says *The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout* So (how) does the BFC matter in this case? *The problem is not the pseudo-element* - What is it? Thanks for the `display:none;` approach - It's debatable whether the fixed wrapping outweights the lost transition and layout shift on first line element hover

Answer (score -2):

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> <span>Fooooooo</span><span>Baaaaaaar</span> ...
</div>
```

This will prevent the spans from wrapping to the next line.

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <span class="word">This</span><span class="char"> </span><span class="word">is</span> ...
</div>
```

By setting `white-space: nowrap;` on the containing element, you can prevent wrapping even when using `::after` elements or having whitespaces in the content.

Comment: *Since in the real example there are whitespaces **which should break**, wrapping everything in a white-space: nowrap; container **isn't an option**.*